# webpage has expired in ie7 no back button involved

Tags: internet-explorer

Our legacy web app is an xml-xslt combo served by Tomcat.  Recently we added some new features that includes psuedo popups.  We have come across a very SPOOKY problem.  In ie7 we see the "Web Page Has Expired error" for only a single page for this upgrade although the same feature is working in other pages.  But hold on!  The spooky part is that this error only shows up from certain computers in our network and not in others!  We guessed it could be some IE setting, but all the settings are identical.  Any ideas?

Comment: You might have better luck asking at superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

It probably happens when POST request page has javascript that tries to modify html while it has not yet loaded until the end. For example if you have thickbox component call that is not inside jQuery's document.ready block. Weird IE validation bug